# Get row data before Deletion MSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am constructing a MSSQL stored procedure to delete a row from a  table but I want to get the data of the row as a delimited string for storage(audit trails) before deletion.

How best can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could SELECT the columns from the table using the same criteria as for the delete, concatenating the values into a string. You will almost definitely need to use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to change non-character data into a string, and any nullable columns will need to be handled with something like [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)(MyColumn, ''). For example;

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max)
SELECT @s = Col1 + ',' + 
            cast(Col2 as varchar(32)) + ',' + 
            isnull(cast(Col3 as varchar(32)), '') 
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   ID = @IDToDelete
```

Hope this helps,

Rhys